# Is there any way to display the Events in Calendar based on the color set for Event Category without using Calendar Overlays?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, json-formatting, overlay

I have a requirement where I need to show the events in Events list in Calendar View with the background color of the Category Selected.

i.e., If Category is Meeting then event background should be red in the calendar. If Category is Business then the event background should be yellow in the calendar.

I tried to achieve that using the Column JSON Formatting by adding below JSON but it is not getting reflected in calendar view.

```
    {  
    "elmType": "div",  
    "txtContent": "@currentField",  
    "style": {  
      "color": "#fff",  
      "padding-left": "14px",  
      "background-color": {  
        "operator": "?",  
        "operands": [  
          {  
            "operator": "==",  
            "operands": [  
              "@currentField",  
              "Meeting"  
            ]  
          },  
          "#2ECC71",  
          {  
            "operator": "?",  
            "operands": [  
              {  
                "operator": "==",  
                "operands": [  
                  "@currentField",  
                  "Work hours"  
                ]  
              },  
              "#E74C3C",  
              {  
                "operator": "?",  
                "operands": [  
                  {  
                    "operator": "==",  
                    "operands": [  
                      "@currentField",  
                      "Business"  
                    ]  
                  },  
                  "#F1C40F",""
                ]  
              }  
            ]  
          }  
        ]  
      }  
    }  
  }
```

I don't want to use Calendar Overlays as goal is to have single calendar only.

**Note:** List is in Modern SharePoint Online site.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Expected Output:
[image]

How it looks:
[image]